# Automatic backup of Jenkins data when EC2 is terminating

Tags: linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2, terraform, systemd

A brief background - I have my Jenkins installed in EC2 (Linux2) with EFS backend - and everything is rolled out using terraform and shell scripts. I am trying to derive a 2 part solution to backup and restore Jenkins data

- in the first part, I need to backup my Jenkins data in an S3 bucket when I terminate the EC2 instance
- in the 2nd part, get the data back from that S3 when I deploy the infra.
  Few facts,
- `/var/lib/jenkins` is mounted to an EFS
- I do not destroy that EFS even if the rest of the infa is destroyed.
- I do not have ELB or auto-scaling as I do not need it for home lab
- This is for my home lab setup where I do not want to keep Jenkins EC2 running when I am not using it and destroy the infra but just keep the data when I need to fire up a new Jenkins.

I am able to do the 2nd part and able to retrieve data back into Jenkins. However I am stuck in the first part. Below shell script "backup_backend.sh" works perfectly when I run it manually from within EC2.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl stop jenkins
sudo tar -czvf jenkins-backup.tar.gz /var/lib/jenkins
aws s3 cp jenkins-backup.tar.gz s3://XXX-jenkins-backup/jenkins-backup.tar.gz
```

Now I created a service script which will trigger when EC2 is terminated and for that I have a service script as below residing in `/etc` folder in EC2.:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shutdown Service
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
Requires=network-online.target network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
KillMode=none
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/etc/backup_backend.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=900

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now there is another script which installs Jenkins and other related packages on EC2 and I kept it within null_resouce block in my terraform code. As part of that script I run the below commands to add the above service:

```
sudo cp /tmp/shutdown.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/shutdown.service
sudo systemctl enable shutdown.service
sudo systemctl start shutdown.service
```

My problem is this service indeed gets triggered when I reboot or terminate EC2, but the zip file size is a lot lesser than when I run "backup_backend.sh" script manually. I am guessing it's a problem with the service script. Is it a timeout issue or anything else? Can anybody suggest what should be the solution?

Comment: Q: why not just write  shell script that a) performs the backup, then b) does a "shutdown -h now" from within the EC2?  This is simple, and it should mitigate the risk of inadvertently terminating before the backup is completed.  Q: Have you checked the "smaller backup" to verify whether or not it's actually "incomplete"?

Comment: paulsm4, I am pulling down my infra using terraform destroy command. The smaller backup file is indeed incomplete

Comment: [unix.se] is a better place to ask about configuring services.